# How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, padding

I want to fill out a string with spaces. I know that the following works for zero's:

```
>>> print("'%06d'"%4)
'000004'
```

But what should I do when I want this?:

```
'hi    '
```

of course I can measure string length and do `str+" "*leftover`, but I'd like the shortest way.

Answer (score 994, accepted):

You can do this with [**`str.ljust(width[, fillchar])`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust):

> Return the string left justified in a string of length *width*. Padding is done using the specified *fillchar* (default is a space). The original string is returned if *width* is less than `len(s)`.

```
>>> 'hi'.ljust(10)
'hi        '
```

Comment: @simon 's answer is more flexible and more useful when formatting more complex strings

Comment: or @abbot 's if you are stuck supporting old versions of python

Comment: ljust() is now deprecated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776788/python-how-can-i-pad-a-string-with-spaces-from-the-right-and-left for the correct way to do it

Comment: Its gone in python 3? Just wanted to add there is also rjust and center which work much the same way but for different alignments

Comment: ljust(), rjust() have been deprecated from the string module only. They are   available on the str builtin type.

Comment: let me count: 'hi12345678'

Answer (score 604):

For a flexible method that works even when formatting complicated string, you probably should use the [string-formatting mini-language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings),

using either [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```
>>> f'{"Hi": <16} StackOverflow!'  # Python >= 3.6
'Hi               StackOverflow!'
```

or the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method

```
>>> '{0: <16} StackOverflow!'.format('Hi')  # Python >=2.6
'Hi               StackOverflow!'
```

Comment: What if you have '16' in a variable?

Comment: I figured that out as well too. Should have posted it. The docs say this should work for Py2.6, but my findings are otherwise. Works in Py2.7 though.

Comment: I had problems with this type of formatting when I was using national accents. You would want 'kra' and 'krá' to be the same, but they were not.

Comment: @Randy `'{message: <{fill}}'.format(message='Hi', fill='16')`

Comment: Don't use `str.format()` for templates with only a single `{...}` and nothing else. Just use the `format()` function and save yourself the parsing overhead: `format('Hi', '<16')`.

Comment: I would suggest not making everyone who reads your code learn such a "mini language" - unless of course you wrap that logic in a function.

Comment: @simon - I write readable functions regardless of what actual languages I use.  But yes, I'm new to python and mainly write js.  And just because something is standard doesn't mean you should make everyone parse your code.  Regexes are terribly unfriendly to read and are far more standard than python's string formatting mini language.

Comment: @aaaaaa readability is subjective. I liked this answer a lot, it's very concise and clear.

Comment: Yes it's subjective, but some code is more easily learned than others which is what I consider to be "readable".  I think the best way to learn what makes code readable is to work with junior devs or first time coders.  Regex may be considered concise and clear to a few, but the majority have a hard time reading and understanding it.

Answer (score 223):

The [string format method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) lets you do some fun stuff with nested keyword arguments. The simplest case:

```
>>> '{message: <16}'.format(message='Hi')
'Hi             '
```

If you want to pass in `16` as a variable:

```
>>> '{message: <{width}}'.format(message='Hi', width=16)
'Hi              '
```

If you want to pass in variables for the [whole kit and kaboodle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples):

```
'{message:{fill}{align}{width}}'.format(
   message='Hi',
   fill=' ',
   align='<',
   width=16,
)
```

Which results in (you guessed it):

```
'Hi              '
```

And for all these, you can use [python 3.6+ f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
message = 'Hi'
fill = ' '
align = '<'
width = 16
f'{message:{fill}{align}{width}}'
```

And of course the result:

```
'Hi              '
```

Comment: How would you handle varying the message as well?

msgs = ['hi', 'hello', 'ciao']

Comment: @ak_slick You can pass in variables instead of hard-coded values into the format function.

Answer (score 93):

You can try this:

```
print("'%-100s'" % 'hi')
```

Comment: print "'%-6s'" % 'hi' indeed!!

Comment: @simon as someone stuck on a python2.5 system this answer helped me, not a useless answer +1

Comment: Not deprecated any more in 3.3+

Comment: I like this common printf syntax much better. Allows you to write complex strings without countless concatenations.

Comment: For completeness, `"'%+100s'" % 'hi'` would work for putting spaces to the right of `'hi'`

Answer (score 89):

Correct way of doing this would be to use Python's format syntax as described in [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

For this case it would simply be:
`'{:10}'.format('hi')`
which outputs:
`'hi        '`

Explanation:

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
fill        ::=  <any character>
align       ::=  "<" | ">" | "=" | "^"
sign        ::=  "+" | "-" | " "
width       ::=  integer
precision   ::=  integer
type        ::=  "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "E" | "f" | "F" | "g" | "G" | "n" | "o" | "s" | "x" | "X" | "%"
```

Pretty much all you need to know is there ^.

Update: 
as of python 3.6 it's even more convenient with literal string interpolation!

```
foo = 'foobar'
print(f'{foo:10} is great!')
# foobar     is great!
```

Answer (score 63):

Use [**`str.ljust()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust):

```
>>> 'Hi'.ljust(6)
'Hi    '
```

You should also consider [**`string.zfill()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill), [**`str.rjust()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) and [**`str.center()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) for string formatting. These can be chained and have the '*fill*' character specified, thus:

```
>>> ('3'.zfill(8) + 'blind'.rjust(8) + 'mice'.ljust(8, '.')).center(40)
'        00000003   blindmice....        '
```

These [string formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) have the advantage of working in Python v2 and v3.

Take a look at [**`pydoc str`**](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html) sometime: there's a wealth of good stuff in there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `str.center(n)` method. It was just what i was looking for and didn't even know its existance. :D

Answer (score 43):

## TL;DR

```py
text = 'hi'
print(f'{text:10}') # 'hi        '
```

## Longer explanation

Since `Python3.6` you can use f-strings [literal interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

**Variable space:**

```py
value = 4
space = 10

# move value to left
print(f'foo {value:<{space}} bar') # foo 4          bar
# move value to right
print(f'foo {value:>{space}} bar') # foo          4 bar
# center value
print(f'foo {value:^{space}} bar') # foo     4      bar
```

**Constant space:**

```py
value = 4

# move value to left
print(f'foo {value:<10} bar') # foo 4          bar
# move value to right
print(f'foo {value:>10} bar') # foo          4 bar
# center value
print(f'foo {value:^10} bar') # foo     4      bar
```

If you want to padd with some other char then space, specify it at the beginning:

```py
value = 4
space = 10
padd = '_'

print(f'foo {value:{padd}^{space}} bar') # foo ____4_____ bar
print(f'foo {value:_^10} bar')           # foo ____4_____ bar
```

Comment: Today, this should be preferred to the other approaches.

Comment: I found this approach much betther than `ljust/rjust` alternatives.
For example, assuming `zip_code` is an integer, the way to apply some formatting with `rjust` would be `str(zip_code).rjust(3, "0")`, instead the equivalent of this with this approach is `f"{zip_code:0>3}"`. Small and more readable!
Problem? slower.. *only if you care about this. (10% based on my tests)

Answer (score 40):

As of Python 3.6 you can just do

```
>>> strng = 'hi'
>>> f'{strng: <10}'
```

with [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Or, if your padding size is in a variable, like this (thanks @Matt M.!):

```
>>> to_pad = 10
>>> f'{strng: <{to_pad}}'
```

Comment: `f'{strng: >10}'` for filling string with leading whitespace to a length of 10. That is magic. And it is not well documented.

Comment: @changye I believe this is also the default behavior of `f'{strng:10}'`.

Answer (score 21):

you can also **center** your string:

```
'{0: ^20}'.format('nice')
```

Answer (score 10):

Use Python 2.7's [mini formatting for strings](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
'{0: <8}'.format('123')
```

This left aligns, and pads to 8 characters with the ' ' character.

Comment: @simon already gave this answer... why posting a duplicate answer?

Comment: I didn't click the 'new responses have been posted, click to refresh' and so missed it.

Answer (score 8):

Just remove the 0 and it will add space instead:

```
>>> print("'%6d'"%4)
```

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't it be more pythonic to use slicing?

For example, to pad a string with spaces on the right until it's 10 characters long:

```
>>> x = "string"    
>>> (x + " " * 10)[:10]   
'string    '
```

To pad it with spaces on the left until it's 15 characters long:

```
>>> (" " * 15 + x)[-15:]
'         string'
```

It requires knowing how long you want to pad to, of course, but it doesn't require measuring the length of the string you're starting with.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? It's not that I don't believe you, I just want to understand why.

Comment: Sure. The most pythonic way would be to use one of the builtin functions rather than using a homegrown solution as much as possible.

Comment: @MadPhysicist saying that slicing is less pythonic because you should use in built functions is like saying `''.join(reversed(str))` is more pythonic than `str[::-1]`, and we all know that's not true.

Comment: @NickA. That is not a very good analogy. The case you are using as an example is quite valid. However, `(x + " " * 10)[:10]` is in my opinion much more convoluted than using `x.ljust(10)`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I more meant that your comment "The most pythonic way would be to use one of the builtin functions" is not **always** accurate and that they aren't words to live by.  Although in this case it certainly is.

Answer (score 3):

A nice trick to use in place of the various print formats:

(1) Pad with spaces to the right:

```
('hi' + '        ')[:8]
```

(2) Pad with leading zeros on the left:

```
('0000' + str(2))[-4:]
```

This approach is not recommended in Python but the logic is useful for languages and macros that lack quality text formatting functions. :)

Comment: For some reason this is the funniest answer but I like it. Along those lines also consider:
    `min_len = 8` then `('hi' + ' '*min_len)[:min_len]` or `('0'*min_len + str(2))[-min_len]`

Comment: For the number, it would be `('0'*min_len + str(2))[-min_len:]` rather, though this is only for fun, and I recommend the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not mentioned in other answers, I would like to point out that you can use `strings` methods for justificate text.

You have three options at least:

- Left justified:

```
>>> "left justified".ljust(30, "*")
left justified****************
```

- Right justified:

```
>>> "right justified".rjust(30, "*")
***************right justified
```

- Center justified

```
>>> "center justified".center(30, "*")
*******center justified*******
```

I am using python 3.10.13, but I believe it works in most 3.X python versions.

Answer (score -4):

You could do it using list comprehension, this'd give you an idea about the number of spaces too and would be a one liner.

```
"hello" + " ".join([" " for x in range(1,10)])
output --> 'hello                 '
```

Comment: ...and then you get a string that is 22 (len("hello")+17 :( ) characters long--that didn't go well. While we are being funny we could do `s = "hi"` ; `s + (6-len(s)) * " "` instead (it is ok when the result is negative). However, answers which use whatever framework feature that addresses the exact issue will be easier to maintain (see other answers).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, the amount of space needed is unknown as str lengths vary.