# How can I pad a string with spaces from the right and left?

Tags: python, string

I have two scenarios where I need to pad a string with whitespaces up to a certain length, in both the left and right directions (in separate cases). For instance, I have the string:

```
TEST
```

but I need to make the string variable

```
_____TEST1
```

so that the actual string variable is 10 characters in length (led by 5 spaces in this case).
**NOTE**: I am showing underscores to represent whitespace (the markdown doesn't look right on SO otherwise).

I also need to figure out how to reverse it and pad whitespace from the other direction:

```
TEST2_____
```

Are there any string helper functions to do this? Or would I need to create a character array to manage it?

Also note, that I am trying to keep the string length a variable (I used a length of 10 in the examples above, but I'll need to be able to change this).

Any help would be awesome. If there are any `python` functions to manage this, I'd rather avoid having to write something from the ground up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can look into [`str.ljust` and `str.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) I believe.

The alternative is probably to use the [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) method:

```
>>> '{:<30}'.format('left aligned')
'left aligned                  '
>>> '{:>30}'.format('right aligned')
'                 right aligned'
>>> '{:^30}'.format('centered')
'           centered           '
>>> '{:*^30}'.format('centered')  # use '*' as a fill char
'***********centered***********'
```

Comment: @Brett -- It looks like those are deprecated.  I've updated with another alternative which isn't ;-)

Comment: The [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) and `rjust` methods are _not_ deprecated; you just linked to the ancient functions from the `string` module, which were only needed in the pre-2.3 days when builtin types weren't like classes and only had methods as a special case.

Comment: how do you make 30 a variable?

Comment: @Raksha -- something like `'{:>{width}}'.format('right aligned', width=30)` works.

Answer (score 17):

Via f-strings (Python 3.6+) :

```
>>> l = "left aligned"
>>> print(f"{l:<30}")
left aligned                  

>>> r = "right aligned"
>>> print(f"{r:>30}")
                 right aligned

>>> c = "center aligned"
>>> print(f"{c:^30}")
        center aligned
```

Comment: However, these are not f-string-specific and only work when you want to align a string (not a number or, say, a tuple or list). You can use exactly the same syntax in f-strings as in format, as in the other answer. So, for example: `f'{right_stuff:>{width}}'` or `f'{left_stuff:<{width}}'`.