# Best way to split multi values of columns into multiple rows in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is how my data looks,

```
emp_id  col1  col2  col3
1234,abc|de,2020|2011,89
5639,ma,2010|2019,90
```

This is how data need to be changed and saved into the file

```
 emp_id  col1  col2  col3
 1234    abc   2020  89
 1234    abc   2011  89
 1234    de    2020  89
 1234    de    2011  89
 5639    ma    2010  90
 5639    ma    2019  90
```

Is there an easy way to do this in python?

Comment: use string split https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split and  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join join. If you want data in a fixed width format.. use {:<n} or {:>n} with an f string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776788/python-how-can-i-pad-a-string-with-spaces-from-the-right-and-left https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ and finally https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/

Comment: I need to add the splitted multivalues to the new rows

Comment: right so as you read each row split first by the commas.. then with 2nd/3rd cols.. split again with | and nest inside of loops. So as you read from one file - you manipulate the line you read, format it and output it to a second file. All the links will give you the building blocks to achieve what you desire.

Comment: `df.transform(lambda x: x.str.split('|') if x.name in ['col1', 'col2'] else x).explode('col1').explode('col2')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace the pattern in pandas datframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782954/replace-the-pattern-in-pandas-datframe)

Comment: Actually that question is to replace patterns and this one is to split the multivalued columns :-(

Comment: @JGFMK Am I causing confusion

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have the easiest way but the following code works on your example:

```py
import pandas as pd
# read your example
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        r"""emp_id,col1,col2,col3
1234,abc|de,2020|2011,89
5639,ma,2010|2019,90"""
    )
)

# split and expand the column with pipe sign
# expanded_col1 and expanded_col2 are dataframes
# rename the column in order to find them after
expanded_col1 = df.col1.str.split('|', expand=True).rename(
    lambda x: f'col1_{x}', axis='columns'
)
expanded_col2 = df.col2.str.split('|', expand=True).rename(
    lambda x: f'col2_{x}', axis='columns'
)

# create all combinations from values of string split
to_concat = []
for col1, col2 in itertools.product(expanded_col1, expanded_col2):
    to_concat.append(
        pd.concat(
            [
                # put back the initial column name
                expanded_col1.loc[:, [col1]].rename(
                    lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis='columns'
                ),
                expanded_col2.loc[:, [col2]].rename(
                    lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis='columns'
                ),
            ],
            axis='columns',
        ).dropna()
    )


result = pd.merge(  # merge combinations and other columns
    df.drop(['col1', 'col2'], axis='columns'),  # drop initial split columns
    pd.concat(to_concat), # concat all combinations
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
)
```

Result:

```
   emp_id  col3 col1  col2
0    1234    89  abc  2020
0    1234    89  abc  2011
0    1234    89   de  2020
0    1234    89   de  2011
1    5639    90   ma  2010
1    5639    90   ma  2019
```