# Replace the pattern in pandas datframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is how my data looks,

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1234,|$||$|,2020|$|2011,|$||$|
5639,|$|,2010|$|2019,|$||$||$|
```

|$| is used as delimiter to separate multivalue column.
So here, there is a situation with empty data in multi valued attribute.
I need this to be replaced with empty like mentioned below.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1234,,2020|$|2011,
5639,,2010|$|2019,
```

Can someone help me with this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to remove any redundant delimiters that produce empty strings, you can try this regex `(?<=^)(\|\$\|)+|\|\$\|(?=$|\|\$\|)`, what it does is match a delimiter if it is at the ends of string or followed by another delimiter:

```
(?<=^)(\|\$\|)+|\|\$\|(?=$|\|\$\|)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    match all delimiters from beginning of string
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  match delimiter if it is at the end of string or followed by 
                                   another delimiter
```

And then you can use `.str.replace` to remove all matched delimiters:

```
print(df)
#   col1    col2         col3         col4
#0  1234  |$||$|  2020|$|2011       |$||$|
#1  5639     |$|  2010|$|2019    |$||$||$|
#2  5639   |$|33  2010|$|2019  |$||$|22|$|
#3  5639   22|$|  2010|$|2019  11|$||$||$|

pattern = r"(?<=^)(\|\$\|)+|\|\$\|(?=$|\|\$\|)"

def clean_delim(col):
    if col.dtype == 'object':
        return col.str.replace(pattern, '')
    else:
        return col
        
print(df.apply(clean_delim))

#   col1 col2         col3 col4
#0  1234       2020|$|2011     
#1  5639       2010|$|2019     
#2  5639   33  2010|$|2019   22
#3  5639   22  2010|$|2019   11
```

Or just do `df.replace(pattern, '', regex=True)` as @Andy

Check [full example here](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/251e4340.py).

Answer (score 2):

Assume you already read data into dataframe `df`. Try this

```
df_final = df.replace(r'^(\|\$\|)+$', '', regex=True)

Out[632]:
   col1 col2         col3 col4
0  1234       2020|$|2011
1  5639       2010|$|2019
```

If you want to save the result to `csv` file, do this additional step

```
df_final.to_csv('t.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

After converting the above csv to dataframe, can you try below -

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x if all(x.split(r'|$|')) else '')
```