# add X zero for a string by python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using something like:

```
tmp=fileA.read(4)
outfile.write(tmp)
```

But there comes the problem if fileA is reaching the end and only 2 bytes is left. In that case, the content of tmp will be

```
xx (Not XXXX any more)
```

And I would like to compensate the missing x by 0, so it can be like

```
xx00
```

When I write into the file outfile

THe question is, I know I can use function

```
len(tmp)
```

to know how many 0 I need to add, is there any easy way to do this adding operation?

I can think of

```
if len(tmp) == 2 : tmp = tmp + "00"
elif len(tmp) == 3: .......
```

But this is some kind of "stupid" method.

Is there a way to do it like:

```
tmp << (4-len(tmp)) | "0000"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you describe the *actual problem* you are trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fill out a python string with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out simple program where '1.txt' contains some bytes data and we are reading 4 byte each.

```
fp1 = open("1.txt", "r") 
fp2 = open("2.txt", "w")

while True:
    line = fp1.read(4).strip()  if not line: # end of file checking          break
    # filling remaining byte with zero having len < 4
    data = line.zfill(4)[::-1]
    print "Writting to file2 :: ", data
    fp2.write(line)
fp1.close() 
fp2.close()
```

Comment: Doesn't that reverse numbers? Like if fp1.read(4) is 32, the result would be 2300 ?

Comment: You should alway use the with statement when opening a file or otherwise use a try, except, finally block in order to safely close the file stream.

Answer (score 9):

Str has a function for what you are trying to do:

```
tmp=fileA.read(4)
tmp.ljust(4, '0')
outfile.write(tmp)
```

Ex:

```
'aa'.ljust(4, '0') => 'aa00'
```

Comment: that's just what I want. Thanks a lot

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest `(tmp + '0000')[:4]`, not being aware of `ljust`.