# How to format text with style

Tags: python

A code below:

```
info={'Resolution':'640x360', 'DisplayResolution': '640x360', 'Display Channels':'R,G,B,A'}
for key in info:
    print (key + str(info[key].rjust(45,'.')))
```

produces a following output:

```
Resolution......................................640x360
DisplayResolution......................................640x360
Display Channels......................................R,G,B,A
```

But I would like to get:

```
Resolution.............................................640x360
DisplayResolution......................................640x360
Display Channels.......................................R,G,B,A
```

How to achieve this?

EDITED:

Thanks everyone for your valuable input. Here is a summary of the code I put together based on your suggestions:

```
ROW_SIZE=0
for key, value in info.iteritems():
    if not key or not value: continue
    key=str(key)
    value=str(value)
    total=len(key)+len(value)+10
    if ROW_SIZE<total: ROW_SIZE=total

result=''
if ROW_SIZE:
    for key in info:
        result+=(key+str(info[key]).rjust(ROW_SIZE-len(key),'.'))+'\n'
print result
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [fill out a python string with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces) The function already exists. Just replace the space with a dot and you have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way would be to keep track of word length and have a variable for number of spaces left and define an overall space (say 45 as length before resolution and color information)

```
 for key in info:
      print (key+str(info[key]).rjust(45-len(key),'.'))
```

One more thing, you may not need str() starting with info[key]. strings are right justified so if the output continues, it is unecessary. Otherwise perform my fix.

Comment: This is great. Exactly what I need since this approach takes into the account the variable strings length and produces a consistent result. I posted what I ended up with on `EDITED` of my original question.

Answer (score 8):

Place the periods as a filler for the key, not the value:

```
info = {'Resolution':'640x360', 'DisplayResolution': '640x360',
      'Display Channels':'R,G,B,A'}
for key, value in info.items():
    print('{k:.<55}{v}'.format(k=key, v=value))
```

yields

```
Resolution.............................................640x360
DisplayResolution......................................640x360
Display Channels.......................................R,G,B,A
```

The above using the newer [format method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). Alternatively, using old-style string formatting:

```
for key,value in info.items():
    print('%s%s' % (key.ljust(55, '.'), value))
```

Comment: I didn't know you this was possible in python, thanks for teaching me something. +1

Answer (score 2):

I would use a set row length and calculate the number needed for `rjust` like

```
info={'Resolution':'640x360', 'DisplayResolution': '640x360', 'Display Channels':'R,G,B,A'}
ROW_SIZE = 100 
for key in info:
    dots = ROW_SIZE - len(key) - len(info[key])
    print (key + str(info[key].rjust(dots,'.')))
```

Comment: I believe in this case he wants `ljust`.

Comment: I apologize, I have steered you wrong and `rjust` was correct after all. I didn't realize it right away until I ran the code. You were correct the first time. (Here's your rollback badge.)

Answer (score 2):

Just make the `rjust` value dynamic to a desired total length:

For example:

```
info={'Resolution':'640x360', 'DisplayResolution': '640x360', 'Display Channels':'R,G,B,A'}
desired_length = 55
for key in info:
    num_dots = desired_length - len(key) + len(info[key])
    print (key + str(info[key].rjust(num_dots,'.')))
```

Output:

```
Resolution.............................................640x360
DisplayResolution......................................640x360
Display Channels.......................................R,G,B,A
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want two columns lined up even if the right column is a different width, you can do:

```
info={'Resolution':'640x360', 'DisplayResolution': '640x360',
      'Display Channels':'R,G,B'}

keys_col=max(len(max(info.keys(), key=len)), 35)    
val_col=max(len(max(info.keys(), key=len)), 10)
for k in info:
    v=info[k]
    line=k.ljust(keys_col, '.') + v.rjust(val_col, '.')
    print line
```

Prints:

```
Resolution...................................640x360
DisplayResolution............................640x360
Display Channels...............................R,G,B
```

Or, with `format` you can do:

```
for k in info:
    v=info[k]
    print '{0:.<{c0}}{1:.>{c1}}'.format(k, v, c0=keys_col, c1=val_col)
```

Comment: FWIW, `f(max(it, key=f))` is better spelt just `max(map(f, it))`.

Comment: Oh, and your `for` loop should be `for k, v in info.items()`.