# I need to reverse the output format of a printed triangle using O's

Tags: python, formatting, output

I need to reverse the output format of a printed triangle using O's

my code is

```
userRows=int(input("Enter a positive number less than or equal to 20!"));

while((userRows>21) or (userRows<0)):
      userRows=int(input("Try again! Please enter a positive number less than or equal to 20."));

rows=1;
while(rows<=userRows):
    columns=1;
    while(columns<=rows):
        print("O",end='');
        columns=columns+1;
    print('');    
    rows=rows + 1;
```

the output is

```
Enter a positive number less than or equal to 20!20
O
OO
OOO
OOOO
OOOOO
OOOOOO
OOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

I'm trying to get this to align from right to left, instead of left to right(as shown above).

Comment: so put in some extra code to print as many spaces as there AREN'T o's on the line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fill out a python string with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> userRows=int(input("Enter a positive number less than or equal to 20!"));
Enter a positive number less than or equal to 20!20
>>> for i in range(userRows):
...    print ' '*(userRows-i)+'0'*i
... 

                   0
                  00
                 000
                0000
               00000
              000000
             0000000
            00000000
           000000000
          0000000000
         00000000000
        000000000000
       0000000000000
      00000000000000
     000000000000000
    0000000000000000
   00000000000000000
  000000000000000000
 0000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

print n(user input - number of iteration )white space before print 'o'

```
def displayTriganle(userInput):
        [print(' '*(userInput-i)+ 'o'*i) for i in range(1,userInput+1)]


                   o
                  oo
                 ooo
                oooo
               ooooo
              oooooo
             ooooooo
            oooooooo
           ooooooooo
          oooooooooo
         ooooooooooo
        oooooooooooo
       ooooooooooooo
      oooooooooooooo
     ooooooooooooooo
    oooooooooooooooo
   ooooooooooooooooo
  oooooooooooooooooo
 ooooooooooooooooooo
oooooooooooooooooooo
```