# How to fill string to length?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string, for example

```
s1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egesta'

s2 = 'Lorem'
```

and I need to fill it by "_" (or other char) to length which is a multiple of 20, like this:

```
s1f = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egesta_____'

s2f = 'Lorem____________________'
```

How would I do it? I know that I can use ljust but I don't know how to calculate length of the rest.

Comment: Just fill it with `20 - len(sf1) % 20` characters.  `len(sf1)` will give you the number of characters in the line.  `% 20` will give you the remainder when dividing by 20, and `20 - ` will give you the number of additional characters needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fill out a python string with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 string_to_modify = "something"
 str_ = ''
 for i in range(20 - len(string_to_modify ) % 20)
     str_ = str_+"_"
 string_to_modify = string_to_modify + str_
```

Comment: You're copying the string far too many times. Use `ljust` or at least `str_ = '_' * 20-len(str_)%20`.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos You missunderstand me sorry fo the lack of clarity I edited my answer to explain what I mean.

Comment: @farhawa Still wrong. You're still copying the string too much. Very inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

There is a method for that called [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust):

```
>>> s2f = 'Lorem'
>>> s2f = s2f.ljust(len(s2f) + (20 - len(s2f) % 20), '_')
>>> s2f
'Lorem_______________'
```

To reduce the clutter in a single line, you just make a separate function:

```
>>> def get_multiples(string):
        return len(string) + (20 - len(string) % 20)
```

Then,

```
>>> s2f = s2f.ljust(get_multiples(s2f), '_')
```

Comment: He want to fill it by "_" (or other char) to length which is a multiple of 20 BUT this just fill the string until reaching 20 as lenght

Comment: @farhawa Thanks, missed that part. Edited now.

Comment: Dear @Zizouz212 The next time you provide a link to the method kindly mention the name of the method. Do not provide a hyperlink on other words. It would help people discover the documentation link with more ease. I have done it this time for you before upvoting. Regards.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks for letting me know. Will do next time and every time afterwards! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function with sberry's "20 - len(sf1) % 20" idea.

```
def charfiller(the_string, filler_character, multiple_of):
    extra_characters = multiple_of - len(the_string) % multiple_of
    the_string = the_string + (filler_character * extra_characters)
    return the_string


s1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse     egesta'
s2 = 'Lorem'
s1_filled = charfiller(s1, '_', 20)
s2_filled = charfiller(s2, '_', 20)
print s1_filled
print s2_filled
print len(s1_filled)
print len(s2_filled)
```

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse egesta_____
> Lorem_______________
>
> 80
>
> 20