# Printing string with two columns

Tags: python, string, printing, multiple-columns

I'm trying to print a string with two fixed columns.  For example, I'd like to be able to print:

```
abc       xyz
abcde     xyz
a         xyz
```

What is the correct way to format the output string when printing to achieve this?  Also, how is this done before version 2.6 and after version 2.6?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use format and mention fix spaces between columns

```
'{0:10}  {1}'.format(s1, s2)
```

Old Style formatting

```
'%-10s' '%s' % (s1,s2)
```

Comment: Old Style - '%-10s' '%s' % (s1,s2), But not sure how old it is

Comment: Nice!  That works perfectly.  Why does the second string receive the adjustment of the formatting on the first string?  I would think it should be `"%s %-10s"`, but that's wrong.

Comment: What I understand '%-10s' means left aligned with max 10 spaces at right. 
I refer https://pyformat.info/

Comment: this works great and is also clean and simple! thanks!

Comment: How would I print multiline text to columns?

Answer (score 2):

This should work for all lengths of the elements (assuming they are strings. This assumes your data is in two seperate lists `first` and `second`.

```
maxlen = len(max(first, key=len))

for i,j in zip(first, second):
    print "%s\t%s" % (i.ljust(maxlen, " "), j)
```

This works in Python 2.x, before and after 2.6.

Comment: Nice solution.  This still wouldn't allow me to place the second column exactly 20 spaces from the start of the string each time though, correct?

Comment: Sure, by ignoring the first line and replacing `maxlen` with `20`.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to >=python3.6

```
s1='albha'
s2='beta'

f'{s1}{s2:>10}'

#output
'albha      beta'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of doing this and it depends on how the data is stored.  Assumining your data is stored in equal length lists:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    print(“%3i\t%3i” %(list1[i]，list2[i]))
```

This will work in all versions of python.  The 3i ensures the output has a field width of 3 characters

Comment: Wouldn't that produce a misaligned output?  The second column wouldn't be in a fixed position if the first `%d` changes length.  It would just be one tab off from the last character.

Comment: You are right I have corrected the answer to show padding to 3 characters

Comment: Is there some way to produce the second `%i` 20 spaces from the start of the string?  That is, not relative to the first `%i`, but relative to the start of the string itself?

Comment: I think you want the .format method https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html for use on strings.

Comment: Yeah, I was just hoping to find some method for doing this before version 2.6.  I'm working on a server that only supports version 2.4.

Comment: Ahh thr python documentation doesnt go back that far to 2.4. But you could use str.ljust http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces and on each iteration calculate the length of the left hand field and pad the second column the right length for consistency