# github repos with all details

Tags: python, github-api

The code below will list all my repos. But is there any way to add 3 more columns to include the creation date, language and type (for e.g. Sources / Forks)?  I'm using the PyGithub package.

```
from github import Github
g = Github("user_name", "passwd")
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    print(repo.name)
```

Comment: What package is `Github`?  There are tons with similar names on PyPl.

Comment: pip install PyGithub

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Repository class](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/7bac694ae5378e51903d38bf7fdd10cbd39cedb9/github/Repository.py#L143) does have (assuming [`PyGithub/PyGithub`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub))

- [`language` field](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/7bac694ae5378e51903d38bf7fdd10cbd39cedb9/github/Repository.py#L488),
- [`created_at` field](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/7bac694ae5378e51903d38bf7fdd10cbd39cedb9/github/Repository.py#L272)
- [`fork` (bool) field](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/7bac694ae5378e51903d38bf7fdd10cbd39cedb9/github/Repository.py#L312)

So you can use those attributes and [print them in column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35236838/6309), using a [`format` string](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) (Python 2.6+, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9996049/6309))

```py
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20}  {: >20}".format(repo.name, repo.language, repo.created_at, repo.fork))
```

Comment: @shantanuo Great! Example at https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/74cd6856de404dc3109360860b712d62458c24eb/tests/Repository.py#L65-L77

Comment: When I try this (with my credentials) I get GitHubException 401 "Requires authentication"