# Format in python by variable length

Tags: python, string, printing, format

I want to print a staircase-like pattern.
I tried this using `.format()` method:

```
for i in range(6, 0, -1):
    print("{0:>"+str(i)+"}".format("#"))
```

But it gave me following error:

```
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
```

Basically the idea is to print this output:

```
     #
    #
   #
  #
 #
#
```

Comment: Just add parenthesis around the string being constructed: `print(("{0:>"+str(i)+"}").format("#"))`

Comment: You can pass its value through format(): `print("{0:>{1}}".format("#", i))`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary the # is fixed. So would it be possible to get it into the string instead of as a parameter? Like `"{#:>{0}}".format(i)`, which doesn't work.

Comment: Near-duplicate: [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently your code interpreted as below:

```
for i in range(6, 0, -1):
    print ( ("{0:>"+str(i))     +     ("}".format("#")))
```

So the format string is constructed of a single "}" and that's not correct. You need the following:

```
for i in range(6, 0, -1):
    print(("{0:>"+str(i)+"}").format("#"))
```

Works as you want:

```
================ RESTART: C:/Users/Desktop/TES.py ================
     #
    #
   #
  #
 #
#
>>>
```

Comment: Yep, the `'}'.format` is the same as the typical `some_object.method`.

Answer (score 18):

### Use f-strings

```
for i in range(6, 0, -1): 
    print(f"{'#':>{i}}")
```

or:

### Use `format()` (instead of concatenating strings)

```
for i in range(6, 0, -1): 
    print("{0:>{1}}".format("#", i))
```

Both solutions give the output:

```
     #
    #
   #
  #
 #
#
```

Comment: This obviously also works with f-strings: `x = '#'; y = 3; z = f'{x:>{y}}'`