# How to align text in Python using variables rather than direct input?

Tags: python, syntax, string-formatting, f-string

I am trying to write a function which takes 6 inputs, a first and last name, two alignment characters and two lengths for alignment. The function is supposed to display the names using the alignment variables like so:

```
|First name  | Last name|
|John        |     Smith|
```

I understand how to do text alignment by directly inputting the desired values with f strings or string formatting e.g

```
{first_name:<12}
```

but how do I substitute the :<12 with variables? I keep getting f string syntax errors. Her is what I am trying:

```
def display_name(first_name, last_name, align1, length1, align2, length2):

    if align1 == "L":
        align1 = "<"

    elif align1 == "R":
        align1 = ">"

    elif align1 == "C":
        align1 = "^"

    if align2 == "L":
        align2 = "<"

    elif align2 == "R":
        align2 = ">"

    elif align2 == "C":
        align2 = "^"

print(f"{|First name:{align1}.{length1}}|{Last name:{align2}.{length2}}|")
print(f"{|first_name:{align1}.{length1}}|{last_name:{align2}.{length2}}|")
```

Comment: Does this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962995/format-in-python-by-variable-length

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. You should not include the `|` in your f-string specifier. Simply swap your `|` and `{}` and your code runs without errors.

```
print(f"|{first_name:{align1}.{length1}}|{last_name:{align2}.{length2}}|")
```

Comment: Thanks. That alteration fixes the syntax error but i'm still not getting the desired output, which is to have the function arguments stand in for the alignment parameters. For instance if I make the print statements                                                                  
print(f"|First name:{align1}.{length1}}|{Last name:{align2}.{length2}|")
print(f"|{first_name:{align1}.{length1}}|{last_name:{align2}.{length2}}|") and call the function display_name("John", "Smith", "L", 12, "R", 10) I get                                         
|First name:<.12|Last name:>.10|
|John|Smith|

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is satisfactorily given here:
[Format in python by variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962995/format-in-python-by-variable-length)

For convenience, here is a minimal example that solves the core of your issue. I haven't though of a way to make it work with f-formatting, but the ''.format() syntax works well here.

```py
stuff='bananas'
('{:<'+str(12)+'}').format(stuff)
```