# CSV to python, text align

Tags: python, csv, alignment

So I have a CSV file which has three columns. I am able to read the CSV file and each row of the table is a list. However, when I try to print them like a table because of the different lengths of the text they are not aligned properly. I believe I have to format them with the % but I am not sure how to make it work.
I've got more rows but for obvious reasons I would have shown only the first 3.

```
North America         USA            Washington
Europe      Republic of Ireland    Dublin
Asia  China     Beijing

This is how my lists look like:
["North America"," USA", "Washington"]
["Europe"," Republic of Ireland", "Dublin"]
["Asia"," China", "Beijing"]
```

Into something like this:

```
North America         USA                       Washington
Europe                Republic of Ireland       Dublin
Asia                  China                     Beijing
```

I do not want to use prettyprint or similiar libraries, as I believe the solution to this problem would be more beneficial to me so that I can understand how things work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Comment: use the tab in python "\t"

Comment: @Mani Tab would still not work because of different length

Comment: @JamesAdams Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using [`ljust()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_ljust.htm)

You can use [`ljust()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_ljust.htm) function (for strings).

`ljust` will pad the string from the right with spaces (or any other char if specified).

Example usage:

```
>>> 'hello'.ljust(10)
'hello     '
>>> 'hello'.ljust(10, 'A')
'helloAAAAA'
```

So when you print the values, just pad them using `ljust`

**Assume having `a` - list a of lists that contains your values:**

```
for b in a:
    for c in b:
        print c.ljust(15),
    print ""
```

## Using [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

You may use the string `format` function for that purpose:

```
>>> '{:10}'.format('hello')
'hello     '
```

**The general format of a standard format specifier is:**

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
fill        ::=  <any character>
align       ::=  "<" | ">" | "=" | "^"
sign        ::=  "+" | "-" | " "
width       ::=  integer
precision   ::=  integer
type        ::=  "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "E" | "f" | "F" | "g" | "G" | "n" | "o" | "s" | "x" | "X" | "%"
```

Another way to use the string [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> '{text: <10}'.format(text='hi')
'hi        '
```

## Using [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

Well, it might be considered more elegant (?) or Pythonic (??) to use that method, but I don't personally like it:

```
>>> ('hello' + 10 * ' ')[:10]
'hello     '
```

## Using print formatting

You can use the percentage sign when printing, for formatting stuff with C style printf...

<s>Nevermind, it's not a good idea. Go look somewhere else!</s>