# I want to change the amount of spaces before a word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to have a user input a word and a certain number of spaces before it: 
e.g. if the user wants 10 spaces before a word it will print:

```
..........foo
```

But without the .'s (That's just to make it clear that there is ten spaces here!). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: checkout [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Comment: How about `10 * " " + "foo"`... Or more generally: `n_spaces * " " + <user word here>`

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard: Dupe question is related to filling up the spaces for constant width of OVERALL string. But here OP want the count of space as constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `str.format` as:

```
>>> space_count = 10
>>> '{}{}'.format(' '*space_count, 'Hello')
'          Hello'
#^^^^^^^^^^
#1234567890 spaces
```

Comment: This one is beauty !!!

Answer (score 1):

As I alluded to in the comments, you can define a function to add any number of spaces to the left of your string:

```
def add_spaces(n_spaces, string):
    return " " * n_spaces + string
```

Test it out:

```
>>> add_spaces(10, "foo")
'          foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your string is `x="foo"`, and you have `pad=10` indicating the number of spaces you want to pad to the left.

Then you can use "format" method for strings in Python in the following way:

```
("{:>%d}" %(len(x)+pad)).format(x)
```

It is basically the same as `"{:>13}".format(x)`, indicating you want to right align `x` within a total length of 13 by padding spaces between `x`.