# How to Convert Each Character of String to ASCII and Pad to Given Length

Tags: python, string, ascii

Using Python 3.4, I am trying to convert a string to padded ASCII values (for each character).

Given a sting:

```
myString = "hello world"
```

Convert each character to ASCII and join back into a single string:

```
asciiString = ''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in myString)
```

This works great, returning:

```
'10410110810811132119111114108100'
```

I would like to pad **EACH CHARACTER** to 7 digits and then join. I've been trying to do this with `format` and have tried so many combinations of `join`, `format`, `str`, and `ord` that I can't even list them all. Can someone please help me figure out how to add format to the "asciiString =" line?  Maybe this can't be done in a single line of code?

Comment: Please update your question with your expected output.

Comment: "h" = 104 (first 3 digits of the returned string).  I would like it to return 0000104.  "e" = 101.  I would like it to return 0000101.  So that the string "he" would return 00001040000101 instead of 104101.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nicest way to pad zeroes to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string) ... quite possible.

Comment: I looked at both of the suggested Stack Overflow questions above, along with many others.  (I searched for 6 hours).  I continued to get errors with my syntax.  Joald's answer worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
asciiString = ''.join(str('{num:07d}'.format(num=ord(c))) for c in myString)
```