# Python 3.6 - Using formatting in a print statement to neatly align output columns

Tags: python

Sorry if this question has been asked before, (Yes, I've checked) but I am writing a program for Python 3.6 and having difficulty trying to align the output of columns like so:

```
  0,     0,  0,   // - undefined - 
 10,    94,  2,   // -----   -----
 10,  9066,  2,   // ----- ! -----
 14, 11528,  2,   // ----- " -----
 24,  9370,  3,   // ----- # -----
 22,  9501,  3,   // ----- $ -----
 29,  9632,  4,   // ----- % -----
 24,  9894,  3,   // ----- & -----
  8, 11706,  1,   // ----- ' -----
```

Note that the numbers do not change the position of the commas.
Currently, when I try to print out like this, the columns are thrown off.

Comment: Can you add the code snippet that you tried with?

Comment: Have you looked at string padding with Python? I think this answer may help you: (use `rjust` instead of `ljust`). https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676676/2780645

Comment: Currently I'm trying to figure out how to put code into my stack overflow post but sure

Comment: @jonathanking Thanks, that looks like what I needed. Should I close this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the method `.rjust` to format each piece of the string. Or use for the `.format` method which allows you to replace fields in a string.

```
my_string = "10".rjust(3)+", "+"94".rjust(7)+", "+"2".rjust(4)

print(my_string)

#or

print("{0:3d}, {1:7d}, {2:4d}".format(10, 94, 2))
```