# How to print two words in same line having equal spacin in python

Tags: python

```
-------- Final Receipt --------
Milk, 2 Litres $ 2
Potatoes $ 7.5
Sugar $ 3.5
```

I want this print statement to be

```
 -------- Final Receipt --------
Milk, 2 Litres    $ 2
Potatoes          $ 7.5
Sugar             $ 3.5
```

here is my print stament

```
for mydata in zip(*list(product_in_basket.values())[:-1]):
        print(mydata[1],'$',mydata[2])
```

and product_in_list is nested dictionary

the code is fully working but need my output style

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ljust`:

```
data = [['-------- Final Receipt --------'], ['Milk, 2 Litres', '$ 2'], ['Potatoes', '$ 7.5'], ['Sugar', '$ 3.5']]
v, _ = max(data[1:], key=lambda x:len(x[0]))
final_data = data[0][0]+'\n'+'\n'.join(a.ljust(len(v)+3)+b for a, b in data[1:])
```

Output:

```
-------- Final Receipt --------
Milk, 2 Litres   $ 2
Potatoes         $ 7.5
Sugar            $ 3.5
```

Comment: @NabinKC For a simpler solution, see Zhenhir's approach.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to fill out the strings with spaces using `ljust`. So that each column is a certain width.

```
header = " -------- Final Receipt --------"

l = [["Milk, 2 Litres", 2], ["Potatoes", 7.5], ["Sugar", 3.5]]

print(header)
for mydata in l:
    price = "$ {0}".format(mydata[1])
    print("{0}{1}".format(mydata[0].ljust(16),price.ljust(16)))
```

I did `len(header)` to find out that your header was 32 characters, so each column takes up half of that now (16).

See: [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

result:

```
 -------- Final Receipt --------
Milk, 2 Litres  $ 2
Potatoes        $ 7.5
Sugar           $ 3.5
```