# How to fill tuple with special character

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a tuple like below:

```
L1 = [(10955, 'A'), (10954, 'AB'), (10953, 'AB'), (10952, 'ABCD')]
```

I want to fill the tuple values with '#' if the length is less than 4.

I want my output as below:

```
L1 = [(10955, 'A###'), (10954, 'AB##'), (10953, 'AB##'), (10952, 'ABCD')]
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable, so you will not be able to change the tuple values from 'A' to 'A###'. You will have to make a copy of the Tuple by replacing the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following list comprehension, where the symbol `"#"` is added as many times as necessary for the string to have length 4:

```
[(i,j + '#'*(4-len(j))) for i,j in L1]
[(10955, 'A###'), (10954, 'AB##'), (10953, 'AB##'), (10952, 'ABCD')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in string method [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust)

```
[(x, y.ljust(4, '#')) for x, y in L1]

[(10955, 'A###'), (10954, 'AB##'), (10953, 'AB##'), (10952, 'ABCD')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[(x, y.ljust(4, '#')) for x, y in L1]
```

I think it is similar to [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

[str.ljust(width[, fillchar])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) is the key.