# What would string5 = "{:~^10}" do to a given string?

Tags: python, format, string.format

Could someone explain what each of these things would do to a given string?

```
string1 = "{:~^10}"

# (another one)
string2 = "{:>10}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: These lines do exactly what they look like. They set the variable to the string given. There is no formatting involved at this time.