# Python formatted String

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, io, text-processing

program 1:

```
print('{:-10}9'.format(12345))
print('{:-10}9'.format(8973955))
```

output of program 1:

```
     123459
   89739559
```

program 2:

```
print('{:10}9'.format(12345))
print('{:10}9'.format(8973955))
```

output of program 2:

```
     123459
   89739559
```

There is only one difference between the two programs. In the first program I used -10 for extra indentation. In the 2nd program I used 10 for extra indentation. Both -10 and 10 are giving indentation on the left side. But I want to do indentation on the right side so that I can produce output like this:

```
12345     9
8973955   9
```

How can I indent in the right side using Formatted String Literals

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces something like this? Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/38228621/3134251 this answer.

Comment: the simple `'{:10}9'` doesn't work for you because you're formatting a number. It will work if it was a string. You can either do `print('{:10}9'.format(str(12345)))` or as suggested in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the *direction* of alignment (alignment option):

```
print('{:<10}9'.format(12345))
print('{:<10}9'.format(8973955))
```

The output:

```
12345     9
8973955   9
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language