# How to properly format displayed data in textbox with tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make it so that the "Add Next Set" button displays the entered data in the textbox. Like for example:

[image: display_example]

The next step would be to apply the data from each previous entry and insert the data into the textbox with this ideal format. As show in the example.

[image: display_example2]

Any tips on how to format the data in the textbox?

Here is some code for context:

```
def insert_into_textbox(): #generates input fields for the next set of items

    #get the inputs
    handling_unit = e3.get()
    pieces = e4.get()
    description = e5.get()
    length = e6.get()
    width = e7.get()
    height = e8.get()
    weight = e9.get()
    classification = e10.get()

    textbox_display = (handling_unit+"   "+pieces+"   "+description+"   "+length+"   "+width+"   "+height+"   "+weight+"   "+classification)
    textbox.insert("end",textbox_display)
    e3.delete(0, "end")
    e4.delete(0, "end")
    e5.delete(0, "end")
    e6.delete(0, "end")
    e7.delete(0, "end")
    e8.delete(0, "end")
    e9.delete(0, "end")
    e10.delete(0, "end")

e1 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #origin zip
e2 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #destination zip
e3 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #handling unit(s)
e4 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #piece(s)
e5 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=13) #description(s)
e6 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #length(s)
e7 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #width(s)
e8 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #height(s)
e9 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #weight(s)
e10 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #class(s)

textbox=Text(master, width=9, borderwidth=5, height=7)
textbox.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=9, sticky="nsew")


b0 = Button(master, text = "Add Next Set", bg="white", fg="black", font=arial8, command=insert_into_textbox)

mainloop()
```

Here is the output

[image: ui4]

How to properly format the display to match the ideal example in picture 2?

Comment: I think you are looking for the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces) post.

Comment: Please make the code in your question a runnable example.

Comment: It is hard to align the text in `Text` widget with the `Entry` widgets because the width of the `Entry` borders may not match the width of a character of the font used in `Text` widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link that Henry Yik provided was very helpful. 
I made the following changes to the code.

```
textbox_display = (handling_unit.ljust(10)+pieces.ljust(11)+description.ljust(11)+length.ljust(10)+width.ljust(11)+height.ljust(11)+weight.ljust(10)+classification+"\n")
```

Or alternatively

```
textbox_display = "{:>12} {:>13} {:>14} {:>13} {:>13} {:>13} {:>13} {:>13}".format(handling_unit, pieces, description, length, width, height, weight, classification)
```

Yields the following result:
[image]