# Write a file in Python

Tags: python, file

I am writing a file that contains two vectors (`x` and `der`):

```
file = open('derivada.dat','w')
for i in range(n):    
    file.write(str(x[i]) + ' ' + str(der[i]) + '\n')
file.close()
```

The `.dat` is like this way:

```
1.0 3.9999999999999973
0.5000000000000001 2.0
-0.4999999999999998 -1.9999999999999973
-1.0 -4.000000000000007
```

How can I modify my code in order to the file be as following? With the columns perfect align.

```
1.0                   3.9999999999999973
0.5000000000000001    2.0
-0.4999999999999998   -1.9999999999999973
-1.0                  -4.000000000000007
```

Comment: why to invent your own file format in the first place?

Comment: Firstly, because it is more pleasant to read

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **`'\t'`** (tab) in order to have the separation you want.

As an example:
`file.write('hello' + \t' + 'world' + '\n')`

```py
file2 = open('derivada.dat','r')
for lines in file2:
    print(lines)
```

**Out[1]:** `hello  world`

To have a "wide" separation you can simply edit `\t` to `'\t\t\t\t\t'` .

`file.write('hello' + '\t\t\t\t\t' + 'world' + '\n')`

It would result in the following:

**Out[2]:** `hello                  world`