# How to print multiple lists in a table format using basic code?

Tags: python, list

So I have been trying to display four lists in a table format but I am not sure how to go about doing that with large spaces in between the column. 
This is what I am trying to get:

```
Number      List1      List2     List3
==========================================
  1          34         16         24
  2          23         27         46
  3          12         17         47
  4          11         43         72
  5          14         22         46
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
list1 = [16, 17, 14, 21, 16, 13, 10, 11, 16, 17]
list2 = [18, 17, 18, 13, 18, 21, 24, 23, 16, 17]
list3 = [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]

print("Number\t\tlist1\t\tlist2\t\tlist3")
print(90*"=")

for x in range(10):
    print(x+1)

for element,element2,element3 in list1,list2,list3:
    print(element,element2,element3)
```

Only the list of 10 prints, how can I print all the other terms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
list1,list2,list3
```

To this:

```
zip(list1,list2,list3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used str().center() to format:

```
list1 = [16, 17, 14, 21, 16, 13, 10, 11, 16, 17]
list2 = [18, 17, 18, 13, 18, 21, 24, 23, 16, 17]
list3 = [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]

print("Number\t\tlist1\t\tlist2\t\tlist3")
print(90*"=")

size_per_col = 5
for i, element1, element2, element3 in zip(range(10), list1, list2, list3):
    print(str(i+1).center(5),
          '\t\t', str(element1).center(size_per_col),
          '\t\t', str(element2).center(size_per_col),
          '\t\t', str(element3).center(size_per_col))
```

Here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/center  is the function `center()` explained in more detail. `format()` will work for the problem too.
An alternative solution without using `str()` is

```
list1 = [16, 17, 14, 21, 16, 13, 10, 11, 16, 17]
list2 = [18, 17, 18, 13, 18, 21, 24, 23, 16, 17]
list3 = [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]

print("Number\t\tlist1\t\tlist2\t\tlist3")
print(90*"=")

for i, element1, element2, element3 in zip(range(10), list1, list2, list3):
    print('{:^6}\t\t{:^5}\t\t{:^5}\t\t{:^5}'
          .format(i+1, element1, element2, element3))
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do that without using str?

Answer (score 0):

You need to zip the list using 'zip' function. I didn't modify much of your code. But, using the below code you can achieve what you want.

```
list1 = [16, 17, 14, 21, 16, 13, 10, 11, 16, 17]
list2 = [18, 17, 18, 13, 18, 21, 24, 23, 16, 17]
list3 = [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]

print("Number\t\tlist1\t\tlist2\t\tlist3")
print(90*"=")

for number,element,element2,element3 in zip(range(1,len(list3)),list1,list2,list3):
    print(number,"\t\t",element,"\t\t",element2,"\t\t",element3)
```