# Append spaces at end of file records which does not have specified length in Python version 2.7.5

Tags: python, linux

I want to append spaces at the end of line if line does not have 80 characters in Python. I have referred [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces) from StackOverflow. Please find input and output as below. Could you please advise me to change any code? Thank you.

**What I have tried?**

I have written the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

input_file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
lines = input_file.readlines()
sys.stdout = open(sys.argv[2],'w')

for line in lines:
    if len(line) != 80:
        print(line.ljust(80, ' '))
    else:
          print(line[0:80])

sys.stdout.close()
```

input_file.txt

```
01010001ADPBI001PEACH   ADP6619200508215754
01010002SCOBIADPADPPW06 200508215754                ADP4
01065008200511P6206  T YS2020050720200511COMO 4005181997      BLTF0510002
```

expected_output_file.txt

```
01010001ADPBI001PEACH   ADP6619200508215754                                     
01010002SCOBIADPADPPW06 200508215754                ADP4                        
01065008200511P6206  T YS2020050720200511COMO 4005181997      BLTF0510002
```

As per above program, I am getting the below output:

```
01010001ADPBI001PEACH   ADP6619200508215754

01010002SCOBIADPADPPW06 200508215754                ADP4

01065008200511P6206  T YS2020050720200511COMO 4005181997      BLTF0510002
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the F-String interpolation and the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), specifically the "align" `<` operator.

So, for each line you would do:

```
line = '01010002SCOBIADPADPPW06 200508215754                ADP4'
space_filled = f'{line:<80}'
```

`space_filled` will output:

```
'01010002SCOBIADPADPPW06 200508215754                ADP4                        '
```

For **Python <= 3.5** you won't be able to use F-String, since they were introduced in Python 3.6. You can still use other string interpolation methods, such as:

```
space_filled = '{:<80}'.format(line)
```

Also, please note that when you do `lines = input_file.readlines()`, the list `lines` will contain the strings for each line of the file, but with a trailing new-line character (`\n`) included. So, when you do the space filling, you are actually appending them in a line below of each line of the original file.

To get rid of this, just update that part of your code, using the `splitlines()` method of the `str` class (and don't forget to close it ;-) ):

```
lines = input_file.read().splitlines()
input_file.close()
```

The entire script should look as follows:

```
import sys

input_file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
lines = input_file.read().splitlines()
input_file.close()
sys.stdout = open(sys.argv[2],'w')

for line in lines:
    print('{:<80}'.format(line))

sys.stdout.close()
```

Comment: which Python version are you running?

Comment: Version is Python 2.7.5

Comment: It shows same output as I mentioned but not as expected_output

Comment: Alright. I have spotted what your problem is. Updated now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215543/discussion-between-revliscano-and-jay).