# Python Beautifulsoup get text under tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all links, titles & dates in a specific month, like March on the website, I'm using `BeautifulSoup` to do so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_link='https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fpage_id=3261.html'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('td'):
   #Text contains 'March'
   #Get the link title & link &date
```

I'm new to `BeautifulSoup`, in `Selenium` I used the xpath: `"//td[contains(text(),'Mar')"`, how can I do this with `BeautifulSoup`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try out,

```
import re
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_link = 'https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fpage_id=3261.html'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

search = re.compile("March")

for td in soup.find_all('td', text=search):
    link = td.parent.select_one("td > a")

    if link:
        print(f"Title : {link.text}")
        print(f"Link : {link['href']}")
        print(f"Date : {td.text}")
        print("-" * 30)
```

---

```
Title : RCBC Lists PHP 17.87257 Billion ASEAN Sustainability Bonds on PDEx
Link : index.html%3Fp=87239.html
Date : March 31, 2021
------------------------------
Title : Aboitiz Power Corporation Raises 8 Billion Fixed Rate Bonds on PDEx
Link : index.html%3Fp=86743.html
Date : March 16, 2021
------------------------------
....
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! it really helps, but may I ask how could it only find Mar in 2021?

Comment: Just fix the regex, ``search = re.compile(r"March.+2021")``

Comment: Hi I am confused with ```td.parent.select_one("td > a")```, is this like ancestor:: in selenium? to choose the parent tag of td ? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To get all links and titles if the "date" has the text "march":

1. Find the "date" - locate all `<td>` elements that have the text "march".
2. Find the previous `<a>` tag using the [`.find_previous()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous) method which contains the desired title and link.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fpage_id=3261.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

fmt_string = "{:<20} {:<130} {}"
print(fmt_string.format("Date", "Title", "Link"))
print('-' * 200)

for tag in soup.select("td:contains('March')"):
    a_tag = tag.find_previous("a")
    print(
        fmt_string.format(
            tag.text, a_tag.text, "https://www.pds.com.ph/" + a_tag["href"],
        )
    )
```

Output (truncated):

```
Date                 Title                                                                                                                              Link
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
March 31, 2021       RCBC Lists PHP 17.87257 Billion ASEAN Sustainability Bonds on PDEx                                                                 https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fp=87239.html
March 16, 2021       Aboitiz Power Corporation Raises 8 Billion Fixed Rate Bonds on PDEx                                                                https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fp=86743.html
March 1, 2021        Century Properties Group, Inc Returns to PDEx with PHP 3 Billion Fixed Rate Bonds                                                  https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fp=86366.html
March 27, 2020       BPI Lists Over PhP 33 Billion of Fixed Rate Bonds on PDEx                                                                          https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fp=74188.html
March 25, 2020       SM Prime Raises PHP 15 Billion Fixed Rate Bonds on PDEx                                                                            https://www.pds.com.ph/index.html%3Fp=74082.html
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! may I ask is ```"{:<20} {:<130} {}"```a regular expression and what does ```print('-' * 200)```mean? thanks :)!

Comment: @Joyce 1. `"{:<20} {:<130} {}"` fills the string with spaces. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces) SO post. 2. `print('-' * 200)` prints  '-' 200 times. I used it for the header. try it out on a regular interpreter.