# how to partially display information from django database?

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework

I want to partially display information from django database. For example:

There is a phone number in the database - +33547895132.
In html i want to display - +3354*****2

models.py:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    num = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True)

    def couple(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        self.num = self.number[:6]
        super().couple()
```

this does not work

Comment: Have you tried converting the information into a string, editing the string, and then displaying it? You could do this in a few lines once the info is a Python string.

Comment: How I can post code here?

Comment: You can edit your post and add code to it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a string with the same length as the original, the below does that.

Your requested output string has 1 less character.

```py
tel = '+33547895132'

def get_masked(input: str, maxpre: int=5, maxpost: int=1, maskchr: str='*') -> str:
    """
    Returns a masked string based on the input values

            Parameters:
                    input   (str): the input string
                    maxpre  (int): how much characters from the start to show
                    maxpost (int): how much characters at the end to show
                    maskchr (str): the charcter used to mask

            Returns:
                    (str):         masked string
    """
    # check to see if we can actually mask this much
    if len(input) < maxpre + maxpost:
        return input
    else:
        fillwidth = len(input) - maxpost
        return f'{input[:maxpre]:{maskchr}<{fillwidth}}{input[fillwidth:]}'


print(get_masked(tel, maxpre=3, maxpost=2))
# this prints:
'+33*******32'


print(get_masked(tel))
# this prints:
'+3354******2'
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25293744/9267296) was used as the base for the solution