# Adding padding for string types

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have written below code to display a leading zero when the string representation of date has less than two digits?

```
'{}-{}-{:02d}'.format('6th', 'Jun', '1933')
```

But it is failing with an error:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the datetime module.

Comment: There seem to be extra quotes in your example code, which makes for invalid Python. Can you please fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces) Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676884/843953)

Comment: I see this answer has been flagged as a duplicate but for your specific case you could try `'{:0>4}-{}-{}'.format('6th', 'Jun', '1933')` which will add a leading zero if there are less than 4 characters in the day representation.

Answer (score 0):

`str.format` doesn't need format codes in most situations. You could simply use:

```
'{}-{}-{:02}'.format('6th', 'Jun', '1933')
```

Comment: this is throwing an error `IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple`

Comment: Did you remove the list display?