# Problem with horizontal printing with end=' ' in python

Tags: python, printing

I've been trying to print horizontally multiple lines elements from a list with different methods (end= ' ', ' '.join(element), etc) but couldn't manage to do it without the last line of element_1 and the first line of element_2 being overlapped.

I tried this code:

```
operations = ['    10\n-  214\n------\n  -204', '   5\n+ 12\n----\n  17', '  8887\n-    7\n------\n  8880']
for operation in operations:
    print(operation, end='    ')
```

and expect to have a layout looking like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBSYM.png

but I got that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlKpt.png

Can anyone give me a clue please?

Comment: Hint: [string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676884/20103413)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change order of items in your list

```
lines = [[] for _ in range(4)]

for operation in operations:
    for i, line in enumerate(operation.split('\n')):
        lines[i].append(line)
```

this way we get a list of lines as we want to print them. We can do that using

```
for line in lines:
   print('    '.join(line))
```