# I want to print a text on the body of a character I've created and I want it to change its width so long words can fit in it

Tags: python

```
print("""
     _^__^_
     |°  °|
    _|\__/|_
   /       \\
  /   {}   \\
 / |        |\\
   |________|
   |   __   |
   |  /  \\  |
   |__|  |__|
    vv    vv

""".format(str(input("Enter text to show: "))))
```

this is the code can anyone suggest me a code to adjust the size of the ascii chracter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fill out a Python string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [str.ljust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) method of string, and put it into a function for convenience

```
template = """
     _^__^_
     |°  °|
    _|\__/|_
   /       \\
  /   {}\\
 / |        |\\
   |________|
   |   __   |
   |  /  \\  |
   |__|  |__|
    vv    vv

"""

def fun(text):
    print(template.format(text.ljust(9)))
```

and a quick test

```
>>> fun("0")

     _^__^_
     |°  °|
    _|\__/|_
   /       \
  /   0     \
 / |        |\
   |________|
   |   __   |
   |  /  \  |
   |__|  |__|
    vv    vv


>>> fun("420")

     _^__^_
     |°  °|
    _|\__/|_
   /       \
  /   420   \
 / |        |\
   |________|
   |   __   |
   |  /  \  |
   |__|  |__|
    vv    vv

>>> fun("hello")

     _^__^_
     |°  °|
    _|\__/|_
   /       \
  /   hello \
 / |        |\
   |________|
   |   __   |
   |  /  \  |
   |__|  |__|
    vv    vv
```

additionally you can mix it with [str.rjust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) so it can move to the other side, and even truncate if it is too long with some slice notation

```
template = """
     _^__^_
     |°  °|
    _|\__/|_
   /       \\
  /{}\\
 / |        |\\
   |________|
   |   __   |
   |  /  \\  |
   |__|  |__|
    vv    vv

"""

def fun(text):
    print(template.format(text[:9].ljust(6).rjust(9)))
```

a quick test

```
>>> fun("a")

     _^__^_
     |°  °|
    _|\__/|_
   /       \
  /   a     \
 / |        |\
   |________|
   |   __   |
   |  /  \  |
   |__|  |__|
    vv    vv


>>> fun("hello")

     _^__^_
     |°  °|
    _|\__/|_
   /       \
  /   hello \
 / |        |\
   |________|
   |   __   |
   |  /  \  |
   |__|  |__|
    vv    vv


>>> fun("abracadabra")

     _^__^_
     |°  °|
    _|\__/|_
   /       \
  /abracadab\
 / |        |\
   |________|
   |   __   |
   |  /  \  |
   |__|  |__|
    vv    vv
```

there is also [str.center](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center), which is another one you can play with...

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change the format to save the string in a value and use the string length `len(string)` to add spaces dynamically through the `*` operation: `"_"*len(string)`.

now you just need to figure out the proper proportions of your character and add the dynamic characters accordingly.

```
string = str(input("Enter text to show: ")) 

print("""
     _^__^_
     |°  °|
    _|\__/|_{1}
   /       \\
  /   {0}   \\
 / |        |\\
   |________|
   |   __   |
   |  /  \\  |
   |__|  |__|
    vv    vv

""".format(string, "__"*len(string) ) )
```